# Add class to element inside <object>

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Let's say, I have this:

```
<div class="en">
  <object data="example.html">
    <div></div>
  </object>
</div>
```

How can I get the class "en" and pass it to the the div inside the object tags using jquery? My problem here is that the content inside "object" is loaded from an external html.

Answer (score 0):

Just work your way down the DOM.

`$(".en object div")` should do you.

If you're loading things into the object externally, wait for them to load and then try

`$('.en object').contents().find('whatever')`

Comment: the problem here is that the elements inside object are loaded from an external html. I can't do it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I did it in another way ;)